# formula for lotto combinations with fixed numbers?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

usually for lottery combinations the formula is "`n! / (k!*(n-k)!)`", e.g., for a 6/49 game it is "`49!/(6!*(49-6)!)`"

is there a formula to calculate the same with `m` FIXED values (e.g., the numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4 are fixed) - 2 numbers are free for choice

i thought the formula is "`(n-m)! / (k!*(n-k-m)!)`" but it doesn't seem so ... because for `m=4` the formular is definitely wrong (for 6/10) and for `m=k` it should be 1)

Comment: if 4 numbers are fixed, no repeats allowed, isnt that just equivalent to a 2/45 game?

Comment: yes it is - k! should be (k-m)! then i think it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have posted as a formula is nothing but [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

It says that k-combination from a set of n elements is given by ***<sup>n</sup>C<sub>k</sub>*** OR `n! / (k!*(n-k)!)`.

Next, the number of combinations of n different things taken m at a time, when k particular objects occur is ***<sup>n-m</sup>C<sub>k-m</sub>*** OR `(n-m)! / (k-m)!*(n-k)!)`.

Comment: i cant click on "this answer is useful" so i say tnx ;)